# Reading a .csv with panda and outputting a single column into a separate .csv file

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I have a large amount of .txt files, using pandas I can read these and create a data frame for the column I need to output to a separate file.

I have a loop which reads the initial data frames and outputs it to a separate file. However, each new file is immediately overwritten for the next one.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

#reads all the .txt files I need and outputs as al list

path = '/Users/uni/Desktop/Readtxtpandastest/6'

files=[]

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
f = list(files)

print (f)


#Reads the list and creates the new files

for X in files:
        cn=5
        df = pd.read_csv((X), usecols = [cn], index_col=False, header = None)
        print df
        for Y in df:
            df.to_csv ('D', index = False)
```

Each new file is immediately overwritten for the next one.

Comment: yeah, because you save file with same name. If you want it as a different file, change file name with iterator. it seems second for loop is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You are giving 'D' as name of file in .to_csv() try to create unique name in loop

```
import datetime
for X in files:
        cn=5
        df = pd.read_csv((X), usecols = [cn], index_col=False, header = None)
        print df
        for Y in df:
            name = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            df.to_csv (name , index = False)
```